# how to pass razor variable to js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC, I would like to pass a row index (razor variable) to a JS.

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Topics.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr id="row-@i"> 

                        <td class="IsReadOnly">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfNoDifficulltySet, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "SubjectTB", @onchange = "CheckNoDiff(this);" })</td>

                    </tr>
                }
```

the js function is CheckNoDiff(this) - I would like to pass the @i  parameter - that is the row index as an argument to the js. How do I do that?
and how do I receive the parameter value on js?

Any help is most welcome - 
Regards,
Lior.

Comment: I'm not familiar with razor, but have you tried `CheckNoDiff(@i)`?

Comment: You want http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/row_index/ like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use JQuery.data() then you can just add an attribute to your text box like so:

```
data-assigned-id="@i"
```

Then remove the parameter from the CheckNoDiff function and within the CheckNoDiff function you can access the value like so:

```
var id= $(this).data('assigned-id');
```